# Logging the conditions within a conditional split transformation (SSIS in SQL Server 2012 and 2016)

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I'm struggling to find out how we can store the conditions inside a conditional split transformation when we run a package. I need a snapshot of the expressions (the whole expressions, not only parameters inside them).

The closest we have got is when an error triggered the SSIS logging and stored the context in the table event_message_context, but we can't figure out how to trigger this logging without an error. We don't need it specifically to come from the built-in logging, we can surely use a script task if you have any suggestions. We run both SQL server 2012 and 2016.

Comment: Maybe research over on https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Could you be more specific about the task you are trying to solve. Are you doing package audit and need to store all conditions, or you want to alter conditions dynamically at start time?

Comment: @Ferdipux Audit - need to store all conditions